# No release date for GET /artist/[id]/albums?

Tags: deezer

In the context of showing all albums of a given artist, as returned by e.g.

http://api.deezer.com/artist/13/albums,

..I would assume it's a pretty common use case to want to sort the albums in discographical order (i.e. by release date) for display.

Yet, I haven't found a way to do that, as the `release_date` property seems to only be available when requesting a single album, and I haven't found a way to affect the sort order in the response.

Am I missing something?

Any help with this is much appreciated! Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just added the `release_date` property on the endpoint `/artist/[id]/albums`.

Jimmy

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a possiblity to do this straight forward at the moment, maybe you can file a request at Deezer's side.

You can get a list of all albums for an artist, open the details for each album individually (album/*albumid*), add them to a list which you can then sort on release date.

Seems like a bit of a hassle for something that will probably be a quick job on Deezer's side, but if you really need it, that's the way at the moment.